# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

I stumbled upon this error while running my application.

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: testing.CacheUpdater': Unable to resolve service for type 'testing.CacheMonitorOptions' while attempting to activate 'testing.CacheUpdater'.

**App explanation**
I am making an application where I periodically(every 10secs) update the MemoryCache with values I fetch from my database.

For this I am using 3 classes, CacheMonitor (which is responsible for the update/override of cache), StudentsContext (which is responsible for fetching the data from the database) and CacheUpdater which is a background service that calls the Update method within the CacheMonitor class.

I have injected them into my DI container like this:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddHostedService<CacheUpdater>();
    services.AddDbContext<StudentsContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]);
    });

    services.Configure<CacheMonitorOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("CacheUpdater"));

    services.AddTransient<ICacheMonitor, CacheMonitor>();

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "testing", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

**CacheMonitor.cs**

```cs
public class CacheMonitor : ICacheMonitor
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly ILogger<CacheMonitor> _logger;
    private readonly StudentContext _databaseContext;

    public CacheMonitor(
        IMemoryCache cache,
        IOptions<CacheMonitor> options,
        StudentContext context,
        ILogger<CacheMonitor> logger)
    {
        this._cache = cache;
        this._databaseContext = context;
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public void UpdateCache()
    {
       //updates cache
    }
}
```

**CacheUpdater.cs**

```cs
public class CacheUpdater{
    private readonly ICacheMonitor _cacheMonitor;
    private readonly CacheMonitorOptions _cacheMonitorOptions;
    private readonly ILogger<CacheUpdater> _logger;

    public CacheUpdater(
        ICacheMonitor cacheMonitor,
        CacheMonitorOptions cacheMonitorOptions,
        ILogger<CacheUpdater> logger)
    {
        _cacheMonitor = cacheMonitor;
        _cacheMonitorOptions = cacheMonitorOptions;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"trying to update cache");
        _cacheMonitor.UpdateCache();
        Thread.Sleep(_cacheMonitorOptions.Interval);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I know that it has to do something with the Lifetime of the services but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It's important to check any exceptions to see if the InnerException or InnerExceptions property is populated. If so, include those details in your question. They're usually populated for an AggregateException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `CacheUpdater` ctor to accept `IOptions<CacheMonitorOptions>` instead of options (with corresponding changes to other code):

```
 public CacheUpdater(
    ICacheMonitor cacheMonitor,
    IOptions<CacheMonitorOptions> cacheMonitorOptions,
    ILogger<CacheUpdater> logger
    )
    {
        ...
    }
```

Also check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

**UPD**

Addressing question from the comments - if you don't want to use pattern from [timed background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks-1) in docs you can do something along this lines (not tested):

```
public class CacheUpdater
{
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
private readonly CacheMonitorOptions _cacheMonitorOptions;
private readonly ILogger<CacheUpdater> _logger;

public CacheUpdater(
    IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
    CacheMonitorOptions cacheMonitorOptions,
    ILogger<CacheUpdater> logger
    )
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _cacheMonitorOptions = cacheMonitorOptions;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) // !
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"trying to update cache");
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                 var cacheMonitor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ICacheMonitor>(); 
                cacheMonitor.UpdateCache();
                await Task.Delay(_cacheMonitorOptions.Interval, stoppingToken); // DO NOT USE THREAD SLEEP HERE!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i get another error: System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: testing.CacheUpdater':

Comment: Cannot consume scoped service 'testing.Models.StudentsContext' from singleton 'testing.ICacheMonitor'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: testing.ICacheMonitor Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: testing.CacheMonitor': Cannot consume scoped service 'testing.Models.StudentContext' from singleton 'testing.ICacheMonitor'.)'

Comment: @schweppes0x it is totally other error. In short you need to inject `IServiceScopeFactory` not `StudentContext`, create when context is needed and resolve context from scope, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618983/2501279).

Comment: @schweppes0x see the update. Note that I have not tested the code so probably it can require some modifications.

Comment: It seems to work now, but the periodical update does not work. For some reason the backgroundservice is not working after the first time.

Comment: @schweppes0x I will need [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see what is the problem. "does not work" is not very helpful to diagnose your problem.