# How to resolve "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory" error?

Tags: c#, graphql

I am running into `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory` error, and I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. I think I am registering all components correctly in DI container.

Looks like I have configured `DBContext` (`ManageUserDocuments.cs`) correctly, but I am not so sure after getting this error. After going through these references which looks similar to my issue, I tried their approaches but no luck. So I am definitely missing something here.

**References:**

- [System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed' In my ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63155869/system-aggregateexception-some-services-are-not-able-to-be-constructed-in-my)
- ['Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions¨1[LibraryData.LibraryContext] while attempting to activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%C2%A8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti)
- [System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738640/system-aggregateexception-some-services-are-not-able-to-be-constructed)

**UserService.cs**

```
using Cosmos.UnitsOfWork;
using GraphQlProject.Interfaces;
using GraphQlProject.Models;
using User = Cosmos.Entities.User;

namespace GraphQlProject.Services;

public class UserService : IUser
{
    private readonly IManageUserDocuments _documents;

    public UserService(IManageUserDocuments documents)
    {
        _documents = documents;
    }

    public async Task<Models.User> GetUserById(string id)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _documents.UserRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(id);

                var convertedUser = new Models.User
                {
                   // DO SOMETHING
                };
                return convertedUser;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ManageUserDocuments.cs (IDbContextFactory Implementation)**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cosmos.EntityFramework;
using Cosmos.Repositories;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Cosmos.UnitsOfWork;

public interface IManageUserDocuments : IUnitOfWork
{
    public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; }
}

public class ManageUserDocuments : IManageUserDocuments
{
    private IUserRepository? _userRepository;
    private readonly C4PDbContext _c4pDbContext;

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dbContextFactory">Instance of a class that implements IDbContextFactory</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public ManageUserDocuments(IDbContextFactory<C4PDbContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _c4pDbContext =
            dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(C4PDbContext));
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _c4pDbContext.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return _c4pDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public IUserRepository UserRepository
    {
        get { return _userRepository ??= new UserRepository(_c4pDbContext); }
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cosmos.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using User = Cosmos.Entities.User;

namespace Cosmos.Repositories;

public interface IUserRepository
{
    public Task<User> GetUserByIdAsync(string id);
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly C4PDbContext _c4pDbContext;
    
    public UserRepository(C4PDbContext c4pDbContext)
    {
        _c4pDbContext = c4pDbContext;
    }
    
    public async Task<User> GetUserByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        var partLine = await _c4pDbContext.Database.GetCosmosClient()
            .GetContainer("c4p", nameof(User).ToLower())
            .ReadItemStreamAsync(id, new PartitionKey(id));

        return partLine.IsSuccessStatusCode
            ? await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<User>(partLine.Content)
            : default;
    }
}
```

**C4PDbContext.cs**

```
using Cosmos.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Cosmos.EntityFramework;

public class C4PDbContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Overloaded constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">Instance of a DbContextOptions</param>
    public C4PDbContext(DbContextOptions<C4PDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        #region User

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<User>()
            .ToContainer(nameof(User).ToLower())
            .HasNoDiscriminator()
            .HasPartitionKey(x => x.id);

        #endregion

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Cosmos.EntityFramework;
using Cosmos.Repositories;
using Cosmos.UnitsOfWork;
using GraphiQl;
using GraphQL.Server;
using GraphQL.Types;
using GraphQlProject.Interfaces;
using GraphQlProject.Mutations;
using GraphQlProject.Query;
using GraphQlProject.Schema;
using GraphQlProject.Services;
using GraphQlProject.Type;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Scoped Services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProduct, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUser, UserService>();

// Repositories
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

// DB Context
builder.Services.AddDbContext<C4PDbContext>();

// Register GraphQL type, query and schema
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProductType>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserType>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProductQuery>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserQuery>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProductMutation>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchema, ProductSchema>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchema, UserSchema>();

builder.Services.AddGraphQL(x => x.EnableMetrics = false).AddSystemTextJson();

// Cosmos
// builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => new CosmosClient(""));

// Units Of Work
builder.Services.AddScoped<IManageUserDocuments, ManageUserDocuments>();
// builder.Services.AddTransient<IManageUserDocuments, ManageUserDocuments>();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseGraphiQl("/graphql");
app.UseGraphQL<ISchema>();


app.Run();
```

When I try to run this, I am getting the following error with 2 inner exceptions:

> System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: GraphQlProject.Interfaces.IUser Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: GraphQlProject.Services.UserService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: GraphQlProject.Query.UserQuery Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: GraphQlProject.Query.UserQuery': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: GraphQL.Types.ISchema Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: GraphQlProject.Schema.UserSchema': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.IManageUserDocuments Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'.)

1st inner Exception:

> ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: GraphQlProject.Query.UserQuery Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: GraphQlProject.Query.UserQuery': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'.

2nd inner exception:

> ---> (Inner Exception #2) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: GraphQL.Types.ISchema Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: GraphQlProject.Schema.UserSchema': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Cosmos.EntityFramework.C4PDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Cosmos.UnitsOfWork.ManageUserDocuments'.

Comment: im not an expert on this but maybe it's because you are using dbcontext in a singleton ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332239/use-dbcontext-in-asp-net-singleton-injected-class

Comment: You didn't add the `DbContextFactory` bits to your service collection, you need to call `services.AddDbContextFactory<C4PDbContext>()`; first. See here `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Comment: @DavidG I tried calling this first (right after `builder.Services.AddControllers();`) but same error.